# Can Malware infect a machine with UAC enabled and not elevating a process

Tags: windows, malware, uac

Is it possible for Malware to infect a machine (i.e. not just a user account) running in a standard user account when UAC is enabled, if the process is not elevated?

I ask because I want to know how protected my machine will be, with others using it online and potentially downloading software.

Comment: Malware will run at the same permission level as the user, unless it can use an exploit, to escalate its permissions.  Vulnerabilities that allow a process to be escalated do exist.  Blocking websites, known to serve malicious content, is the best way to protect yourself.  Having active and passive security software is also required.  The combination of blocking the content, passively scanning your machine, and routinely doing active scan is normally enough to keep your system clean.

Answer (score 0):

Yes malware can infect your computer if you are running as a standard user with UAC enabled.

When you perform any action on a computer - browse a webpage, execute an application, open a file - it is done in the context of your user... meaning that it is done in the confines of your users allowed rights.

As a normal non admin user (or even as a user with UAC prompted admin rights) - these actions can include:

- Copying/replacing certain system files (which will then execute as "system" in elevated rights
- Deploying malware/spyware which simply sits and watches what you do (like enter passwords, sign into online banking etc)

...basically anything your user can do without UAC interaction, malware can do with your users rights

It's very much worth noting that the internet is a 2 way street.  If a user visits a less than reputable site (or even a compromised reputable one) - Javascript, Flash, plugins, the browser itself can all be exploited to remotely execute code on your PC without your knowledge using a whole number of different methods such as XSS (Cross Site Scripting).

If one of these attacks are executed against you - the code being executed will execute as the user which has the browser opened (IE, as your user account)

When this happens to a user, the only real restriction to what can be executed is the rights of the user.

A non-admin, restricted user account gives some form of damage limitation - but the amount of damage done can still be quite large and once your machine is infected - the only real way to ensure you're completely clean again is to wipe your machine, restore your files from backups and start again.. not nice.

It's also worth noting that the horrible crypot locker style infections that are so rampant at the minute don't require admin rights to run - but can still lock you out of every document on your PC (and attached external disks, network drives and so on)

---

Things you can do to protect yourself:

- Run as a non admin user.  You say you are already doing this which is good and at least provides a bit of damage limitation.
- Firewall.  Even the windows firewall is better than nothing (although it's not up to much in my personal opinion)
- Update regularly.  Each bout of windows updates will include security fixes.  New bugs will be found, but at least you will only be vulnerable to newstuff and not old stuff too
- AV, Anti Spyware, Anti Malware etc.. get a highly rated one and keep it up to date.  Granted no AV will catch everything, but an up to date one will do a lot more than an out of date one which will do a lot more than nothing
- Regular backups.  If you do catch an infection - a good set of regular backups which are kept offline (eg external disk disconnected from the PC) will be a godsend when you need to recover
- Dont open things you are unsure of.  Email attachments, facebook messages, websites with a bad reputation etc... stay clear of them if you are even a little concerned about their authenticity.

Of course, all of this won't guarantee you will stay clear of infections - but it will definitely significantly lower your risk level.

Answer (score 0):

A **Malware** can infect your machine running in a standard user account when **UAC** is enabled and elevate the privilege to get the root access, It's called [privilege_escalation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_escalation)

> Privilege escalation is the act of exploiting a bug, design flaw or configuration oversight in an operating system or software application to gain elevated access to resources that are normally protected from an application or user. The result is that an application with more privileges than intended by the application developer or system administrator can perform unauthorized actions.